# Carbon data missing when explode

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

In Laravel i´m trying to use [Daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) elements in a query. I have

```
 $range= explode(' - ',$request->range);
```

1. 05/05/2008 00:00:00 -> $range[0]
2. 06/06/2008 23:59:59 -> $range[1]

Then i use explode elements in SQL

```
Model::whereBetween('date', [Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $range[0])->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $range[1])->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')])->get();
```

The problem: The SQL return data missing. ¿Any help?

Comment: Show your dump of $range dd($range)

Comment: dd($range) == 05/05/2008 00:00:00 -> $range[0]
06/06/2008 23:59:59 -> $range[1]

Answer (score 0):

Try other way

```
$from = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $range[0])->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$to = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $range[1])->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$model = Model->where('date','>=',$from)
->where('date','<=',$to)
->first();
```

Comment: toDateTimeString() return 'Call to a member function toDateTimeString() on string'.

Comment: What is the result of Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $range[0])->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') ?

Comment: Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $range[0])->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') = 2008-05-05 13:12:54

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this,

```
$range= explode(' - ',$request->range);

$from = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $range[0])->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$to = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $range[1])->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Now check `$from` and `$to` with **`dd()`** and if there is value in it then you can do query,

```
$model = Model::whereBetween('date', [$from,$to])->get();
```

Comment: $from and $to has correct values, but when i insert in SQL return "Data missing".

Comment: "InvalidArgumentException"
file
:
"C:\xampp\htdocs\Noatum\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Carbon.php"
line
:
775
message
:
"Data missing"

Comment: what is the data type of your date in database?

Comment: The date tipe is 'date' with Year-Month-Day Time24:Minute:Seconds.

Comment: Oh, So this should be the problem. Try to change datatype of  'date' to **datetime** and it should work. I think so